# How do I pass parameters to the Azure PowerShell Set-AzVmRunCommand?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

I've been trying to use Set-AzVmRunCommand instead of the invoke alternative, as it gives more options like protected params and better feedback. I've used the equivalent in Az CLI for some time with good results. Documentation is here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/set-azvmruncommand?view=azps-9.2.0

I'm struggling to form the parameter object that it expects, which is described as follows:

```
ALIASES

COMPLEX PARAMETER PROPERTIES

To create the parameters described below, construct a hash table containing the appropriate properties. For information on hash tables, run Get-Help about_Hash_Tables.

PARAMETER <IRunCommandInputParameter[]>: The parameters used by the script.

    Name <String>: The run command parameter name.
    Value <String>: The run command parameter value.

PROTECTEDPARAMETER <IRunCommandInputParameter[]>: The parameters used by the script.

    Name <String>: The run command parameter name.
    Value <String>: The run command parameter value.
```

In az CLI the params are formed rather simply, using a format like the below:

```
--parameters "serverName =xyz" "databaseName =abc"
```

I've tried creating an array of hashtables, an individual hashtable containing multiple entries, etc. but all to no avail. I'm sure that it's obvious to someone out there, so thought I'd ask if anyone knew how to use this correctly? I can't find much out there in terms of extra info or documented examples.

I think I may be supposed to create a hashtable within a parameter object of type IRunCommandInputParameter, just not sure yet, ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.powershell.cmdlets.compute.models.api20210701.iruncommandinputparameter?view=az-ps-latest

Comment: `-Parameter @(@{Name='serverName';Value='xyz'},@{Name='databaseName';Value='abc'})`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - Thank you! That worked straight away, I see from your example that I made a silly mistake on my array of hastables attempt now... Thanks again! :)

Comment: Microsoft will never provide some complex examples in their docs. :) :) :)

Answer (score 1):

From MathiasR.Jessen in comments =

```
Set-AzVMRunCommand ... -Parameter @(@{Name='serverName';Value='xyz'},@{Name='databaseName';Value='abc'})
```

Array containing hashtable for each parameter required. Works just fine, thank you!